# Smart Pointers in templates c++

Tags: c++, c++11

> Create a class template `SmartPointer` that should contain a pointer to any object and delete that same object when the destructor of that class is called. In order for the smart pointer to behave the same way the raw pointer behaves, you must overlap the operator `*` and `->`.

So, this is my task, and I've done this code, but the `->` operator is not okay. If someone knows how to fix it, please help me.

```cpp
template <class T>
class SmartPointer {
private:
    T* x;
public:
    T& operator*() {
        return *x;
    }
    T& operator->(){
        return this();
    }
    SmartPointer(T *X);
    ~SmartPointer();
};

template<class T>
SmartPointer<T>::SmartPointer(T *X) {
    this->x = X;
}

template<class T>
SmartPointer<T>::~SmartPointer() {
    delete x;
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly how your code doesn't work. Include any error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator->` function should return a *pointer*. And it should be a pointer to the wrapped object:

```
T* operator->()
{
    return x;
}
```